# Getting preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405 in chrome WCF service

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf

I am trying to upload image on server, it's working fine on safari but does not work on chrome. I face this error.

XMLHttpRequest cannot load "URL" Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405

// Interface

```
    public interface ISignatureUpload
    {
      [OperationContract(Name = "AddEPCRSignUpload")]
      [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/AddEPCRSignUpload?fileName={fileName}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
      string AddEPCRSignUpload(string fileName, string sigFile);
    }
```

// Interface Implementation code

```
public class SignatureUpload : ISignatureUpload
{    
  public string AddEPCRSignUpload(string fileName, string sigFile)
  {
   // Some Code to upload file 
  }
}
```

// Web.Config

```
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, OPTIONS" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>

<system.web>

</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="SignatureService.WebHttp" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
             maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
             maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
             transferMode="Streamed"
             sendTimeout="00:05:00">
      <readerQuotas  maxDepth="2147483647"
                     maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                     maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                     maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                     maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="SignatureUpload.Behavior" name="SignatureUpload.SignatureUpload">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="web" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SignatureService.WebHttp" contract="SignatureUpload.ISignatureUpload">
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>

<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="web">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="SignatureUpload.Behavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
  multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
 </system.serviceModel>
 </configuration>
```

// JS

```
 var imageInspector =  document.getElementById("sigcanvas").toDataURL("image/png");
          imageInspector = imageInspector.replace('data:image/png;base64,', '');

          jQuery.support.cors = true;
          $.ajax({
              url: 'http://serverip/DCASSigUpload/SignatureUpload.svc/AddEPCRSignUpload?fileName=' + itemID + "~Signature~sigcanvas",
              type: 'POST',
              //data: '{ "sigFile" : "' + image + '" }',
              data: JSON.stringify(imageInspector),
              crossDomain:true,
              dataType: 'json',
              //processData: false, // Don't process the files
              contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
              //contentType: "application/octet-stream",
              success: function (data) {
                  //$("#modal-content, #modal-background").toggleClass("active");
                alert("Done");
              },
              error: OnGetAllMembersError               
          });
```

Comment: just changed  Method = "POST",  to Method = " * ",   work perfect now

Answer (score 0):

Just changed Method = "POST", to Method = " * ", work perfect now